# Uniformly integrable sequence: definition and characterization

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, uniform-integrability

As far as I know, given a positive measure space, $f\in L^1(\Omega)$ is an uniformly integrable function if for all $\varepsilon>0$, $\delta>0$ exists such that
$$\int_A |f| \, d\mu <\varepsilon,$$
with $\mu(A)<\delta$.
It means, for me, that $f\in L^1(\Omega)$ is an uniformly integrable if its integral over a “small” set it is itself “small”.

I guess that, if $(f_n)_n\subset L^1(\Omega)$, thus $(f_n)_n$ is uniformly integrable sequence if
$$\int_A |f_n| \, d\mu <\varepsilon \quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N},$$

$\mu_(A)<\delta$.

${\bf My\; question\; is}$: there exists a characterization which allow to say that
$$\sup_n \int_{\Omega} |f_n| d\mu <+\infty,$$
thus $(f_n)_n$ is a uniformy integrable sequence? If yes, could anyone please give me a reference or a  hint for the proof?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No. Boundeness in $L^{1}$ is much weaker than uniform integbrability. Look at $n\chi_{(0,\frac1 n)}$.

Comment: The unit ball of $L^1$ is not weakly compact (the result "UI iff weakly precompact" for a probability space is the content of the Dunford-Pettis theorem).

Comment: If $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$, then what you wrote is *almost* true: if there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $C:= \sup_{n} \int_{\Omega} |f_{n}|^{1 + \epsilon} \, d \mu < \infty$, then $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly integrable (by Holder's inequality).  This is frequently useful.

Comment: @PeterMorfe thank you for your comment. Could you please give me a reference of what you said? Or, if you want, could you give more details? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @C.Bishop, I added an answer addressing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only probability spaces for which uniform integrability is equivalent to boundedness in $L^1$ are the probability spaces $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mu)$ for which there exists a positive $\delta$ such that each $A\in\mathcal F$ has either probability $0$ or $\mu(A)>\delta$.

Indeed, if such a $\delta$ does not exists, it is possible to find a sequence of sets $(A_n)$ whose probability is in $(0,1/n)$. Let $f_n=\mathbf{1}_{A_n}/\mu(A_n)$. Then $(f_n)$ is bounded in $L^1$ but not uniformly integrable.

If there exists positive $\delta$ such that each $A\in\mathcal F$ has either probability $0$ or $\mu(A)>\delta$, then each sequence which is bounded in $L^1$ is actually bounded in $L^\infty$ (write down the essential supremum to see this) hence uniformy integrable.

Comment: Davide Giraudo, if you take into account $(\mathbb{R}^N, \mu)$ where $\mu$ denotes the Lebesgue measure, the property holds for any Lebesgue integrable function $f$, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

As the answer by Davide Giraudo shows, it is not enough to be bounded in $L^{1}$ in general.  However, it is *almost* enough (provided one is careful in one's use of *almost*).

Suppose $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ satisfies, for some $\epsilon \in (0,\infty]$ and $C > 0$,
\begin{equation*}
\|f_{n}\|_{L^{1 + \epsilon}(\Omega)} = \left( \int_{\Omega} |f_{n}(x)|^{1 + \epsilon} \, \mu(dx) \right)^{\frac{1}{1 + \epsilon}} \leq C.
\end{equation*}
(If $\epsilon = \infty$, use the $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ norm...) Notice we can now apply Holder's inequality to find, for each $\mu$-measurable set $A \subseteq \Omega$,
\begin{equation} \label{E: integrability modulus}
\int_{A} |f_{n}(x)| \, \mu(dx) \leq C \mu(A)^{\frac{\epsilon}{1 + \epsilon}} \quad (*)
\end{equation}
Hence $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly integrable.  In fact, if you want, (*) gives a uniform *modulus of integrability* for $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.  It's even better than that since if only depends on $C$, not the sequence.

Notice that ( * ) is somehow analogous to Holder continuity.  In the same way that a uniform Holder modulus helps get uniform convergence from pointwise convergence (using Arzela-Ascoli), (*) helps improve pointwise convergence to convergence of the integral (via Vitali's convergence theorem).

Comment: Thank you, I’m thinking to accept yours because it is closer to my needs. Moreover, I make you the same question I made to Davide. If you take into account $\mathbb{R}^N,\mu)$, where $\mu$
denotes the Lebesgue measure, the property holds for any Lebesgue integrable function $f$, isn't it?